# Android Studio: Picasso unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So, i am just impementing it in mine gradle file and when i'm writing Picasso.get....... getting unresolved reference on name Picasso, pls help.

Comment: please add reference code

Answer (score 0):

You provide little details but it seems that you want to use the Picasso image library. If the reference is unresolved it means that you do not have the library as a dependency in your project.

In your `app` modules (usually the one by default when you create a project), you should have a build configuration file (build.gradle or build.gradle.kts) where you need to add the dependencies of your project. So you need to add it in the `dependencies` section of the build configuration :

```
dependencies {

    implementation("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8")
}
```

And afterwards don’t forget to execute a "Sync project with Gradle files" in Android Studio in order to have the dependency effectively included in your project.

Comment: I added this line in dependencies a long time ago, I also imported the library via CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S, it did not help.

Comment: So do you see the Picasso dependency if you go into the project panel, switch to Project view instead of Android, scroll down and expand the "External Libraries" ?